# Call items inside list of PySpark data frame

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frame

```
+------------------+----------+------------------+
|        antecedent|consequent|        confidence|
+------------------+----------+------------------+
|         [7, 2, 0]|       [8]|0.6237623762376238|
|         [7, 2, 0]|       [1]|               1.0|
|         [7, 2, 0]|       [5]|0.9975247524752475|
|         [7, 2, 0]|       [3]|0.9975247524752475|
|         [7, 2, 0]|       [4]|0.9975247524752475|
|         [7, 2, 0]|       [6]| 0.995049504950495|
|      [6, 5, 3, 4]|       [8]| 0.623721881390593|
|      [6, 5, 3, 4]|       [1]|               1.0|
|      [6, 5, 3, 4]|       [2]|               1.0|
|      [6, 5, 3, 4]|       [0]|               1.0|
|      [6, 5, 3, 4]|       [7]| 0.820040899795501|
|[9, 8, 6, 5, 1, 2]|       [0]|               1.0|
|[9, 8, 6, 5, 1, 2]|       [3]|               1.0|
|[9, 8, 6, 5, 1, 2]|       [4]|               1.0|
|         [7, 3, 1]|       [8]|0.6228287841191067|
|         [7, 3, 1]|       [5]|               1.0|
|         [7, 3, 1]|       [2]|               1.0|
|         [7, 3, 1]|       [0]|               1.0|
|         [7, 3, 1]|       [4]|               1.0|
|         [7, 3, 1]|       [6]|0.9950372208436724|
+------------------+----------+------------------+
```

I want to make some queries on it, for example filter rows where antecedent does not contain [7,3], I tried this query ,but it seems wrong because 7,3 are integer numbers

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
q = r.filter(~col('antecedent').isin([7,3])).show()
```

The error:

```
"condition should be string or Column"
```

Comment: are you trying to check 7 and 3 individually or as an array [7, 3]?

Comment: I tried first [3] ,then [3,7] and both of them did not work

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `udf` function for checking the condition (**the condition to check for either *7 or 3* to be present in antecedent `column`**) as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
def checkIsIn(array):
    return True in [x in array for x in [7, 3]]

udfCheckIsIn = F.udf(checkIsIn, T.BooleanType())
```

and then use it in filter as

```
q = r.filter(udfCheckIsIn(r.antecedent)).show()
```

You should have output as

```
+------------+----------+------------------+
|  antecedent|consequent|        confidence|
+------------+----------+------------------+
|   [7, 2, 0]|       [8]|0.6237623762376238|
|   [7, 2, 0]|       [1]|               1.0|
|   [7, 2, 0]|       [5]|0.9975247524752475|
|   [7, 2, 0]|       [3]|0.9975247524752475|
|   [7, 2, 0]|       [4]|0.9975247524752475|
|   [7, 2, 0]|       [6]| 0.995049504950495|
|[6, 5, 3, 4]|       [8]| 0.623721881390593|
|[6, 5, 3, 4]|       [1]|               1.0|
|[6, 5, 3, 4]|       [2]|               1.0|
|[6, 5, 3, 4]|       [0]|               1.0|
|[6, 5, 3, 4]|       [7]| 0.820040899795501|
|   [7, 3, 1]|       [8]|0.6228287841191067|
|   [7, 3, 1]|       [5]|               1.0|
|   [7, 3, 1]|       [2]|               1.0|
|   [7, 3, 1]|       [0]|               1.0|
|   [7, 3, 1]|       [4]|               1.0|
|   [7, 3, 1]|       [6]|0.9950372208436724|
+------------+----------+------------------+
```

For checking the condition (**the condition to check for either *7 and 3* to be present in antecedent `column`**) as

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
def checkIsIn(array):
    return False not in [x in array for x in [7, 3]]

udfCheckIsIn = F.udf(checkIsIn, T.BooleanType())
```

and then use it in filter as

```
q = r.filter(udfCheckIsIn(r.antecedent)).show()
```

You should have output as

```
+----------+----------+------------------+
|antecedent|consequent|        confidence|
+----------+----------+------------------+
| [7, 3, 1]|       [8]|0.6228287841191067|
| [7, 3, 1]|       [5]|               1.0|
| [7, 3, 1]|       [2]|               1.0|
| [7, 3, 1]|       [0]|               1.0|
| [7, 3, 1]|       [4]|               1.0|
| [7, 3, 1]|       [6]|0.9950372208436724|
+----------+----------+------------------+
```

Comment: thanks, it looks like "or"  or union ,because I get all items that contain 3,items contain 7 ,and items contain 3&7 together ,and first answer looks like intersection or & operation, all answers are  very useful

Comment: @amal, thats why I aked you if its && or or in the question comment.

Comment: YES,I do not understand question ,but this answer also helpful for me ,because I am working on thesis

Comment: @amal, I have added both ways and more efficient than before :) please have a look

Comment: @amal, I know both the answers helped you, So you can proceed to accept any of it. and please don't forget to upvote when you would be able to. :)